# Wordpress Sermon Browser podcast feed missing length attribute

Tags: rss, podcast

My [podcast feed](http://drcraigjohnson.org/audio-sermons/?podcast) won't [validate](https://validator.w3.org./feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdrcraigjohnson.org%2Faudio-sermons%2F%3Fpodcast) and gives the error "Missing enclosure attribute: length" I see the call for sb_media_size (file size function) within the enclosure tag but no results. This is a WordPress plugin, Sermon Browser. Help appreciated. Thank you!

```
//Prints size of file
function sb_media_size($media_name, $media_type) {
    if ($media_type == 'URLs') {
        if(ini_get('allow_url_fopen')) {
            $headers = is_array($media_name) &&           array_change_key_case(@get_headers($media_name, 1),CASE_LOWER);
        $filesize = $headers['content-length'];
        if ($filesize)
            return "length=\"{$filesize}\"";
    }
} else
    return 'length="'.@filesize(SB_ABSPATH.sb_get_option('upload_dir').$media_name).'"';
}

<enclosure url="<?php echo sb_podcast_file_url($media_name, $media_type).'" '.sb_media_size($media_name,      $media_type).sb_mime_type($media_name); ?> />
```

Answer (score 0):

Used fiverr.com. Solution was reinstalling the plugin. WP wouldn't allow me. The developer went to plugin editor, and changed plugin version to lower, so WP will detect that there's a newer version, and plugin will be reinstalled while settings are kept.